# How would cutting this heated bed in half affect the current draw?

Tags: current, heater

I'm working on a project in which I need a small heater pad. I'm limited to a 12V supply which can provide 12.5A and I am drawing about 3.5A of that with my other electronics.

I have an old AnyCubic I3 Mega heated bed shown below which I thought I might be able to use. Based on [this](https://www.banggood.com/Anycubic-240x220x5_5mm-Ultrabase-Platform-With-Heated-bed-For-3D-Printer-p-1268884.html?utm_source=googleshopping&utm_medium=cpc_organic&gmcCountry=ZA&utm_content=minha&utm_campaign=minha-za-en-pc&currency=ZAR&cur_warehouse=CN&createTmp=1&utm_source=googleshopping&utm_medium=cpc_bgs&utm_content=xibei&utm_campaign=xibei-ssc-za-all-0622) which is not exactly the same bed but I assume probably has similar specs, at 12V and 145W this will draw around 12A.

Looking at the tracks on the underside of the bed I can see that the bed has two heater elements connected up in parallel. I'd like to know what would happen if I were to cut the bed in half right between the two elements? If I could do so neatly enough without damaging the tracks on one half am I correct in thinking that the 'half' heater will draw 6A?

[image: Heated bed]

Answer (score 0):

I cut the tracks to the top half heating element and connected to 12V. My supply draws 4.85A and half the plate gets hot so I guess the answer is yes. Disconnecting one half of the tracks will result in half the current draw. Simple ohms law.

Answer (score -1):

Seeing as the link lists temperature setpoints the bed is capable of maintaining implies that the control circuit isn't just putting 12V to the heating element and counting on the resistance to limit current.  Also, given the likely amount of resistance change due to temperature, I recommend using something like a switch mode DC-DC converter to adjust the voltage you're sending to the heating element, no cutting required.

Comment: Actually, such a thing *does* count on the heater resistance, and then controls the *duty cycle* to achieve heat output appropriate to maintain the desired temperature.

Comment: True, but heater resistance alone provides an approximate upper bound on current, the heater system is still modulating to provide precise control over average current.  Moot point now, but is that heater element rated for constant operation at 100%?  The datasheet seems to indicate that it is more than capable of exceeding its max operating temperature.

Comment: Modulating the duty cycle is an order of magnitude simpler and cheaper than DC-DC conversion: which is why things actually work that way, and not in the way you propose.  And no, a DC-DC converter would not make it "safer" as the heat output sufficient to get up to temperature in a reasonable amount of time or maintain a large part in a cold drafty room would be too much for a bare bed in still air on a hot day; it has to be adjustable, and in any system an uncorrected error in the adjustment is indeed an issue.